# Trying to find fantasy novel set in wizarding world where women are second class citizens

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to find a novel and I can't remember what it was called or the author. Here's what I remember:

- Read it within the past 10 years
- Read it as an English ebook
- Young adult (possibly new adult)
- Men are wizards, women have magic that can be used by men
- Women are treated as inferior
- Main character is a young woman who is married off to a foreign wizard. She is the oldest of a bunch of girls.

More points that I remember that may be spoilers:

> - Main character is originally supposed to be married off to an older, local, abusive man, but ends up marrying foreigner when he kills main character's fiance for abusing her.
> - Main character's husband sees women as equals and treats her much better than a local man would. She eventually falls in love with him.
> - There is a test (maybe a blood test?) that women take to determine how much magic they have.
> - There is some strange wedding ceremony where main character's husband forces her to feel various different emotions.
> - At one point main character's husband congratulates her on her new baby sister. She thinks he is mocking her, while he is really being sincere.
> - Main character and her husband are at a dinner/gathering where a young woman is killed/sacrificed.

Comment: Hey, welcome! This is a very good start, but I'm sure you can add some more details - what language was it in? Where did you read it? Was it a hard copy, or ebook, or what? Also check out https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question for some more guidance on writing a Story-ID question ;)

Comment: Possibly the Legends of Alaia series?

Comment: @JohnP: By Cate Rowan? Is the first one The Source of Magic? If that's what you're referring to, it's not what I'm looking for.